# How to add a text shadow to my table using CSS

Tags: html, css, text, shadow

I have a design using tables [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBqXY.jpg).

Like the title image, I'd like to add a nice glow around the text inside that black table.

I've tried searching the net regarding CSS text shadows (like [this article on CSS text-shadow](http://line25.com/articles/using-css-text-shadow-to-create-cool-text-effects), for instance).

When I put them into my page however, I can't seem to get them to work inside the table, or at all.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: "Not sure what I'm doing wrong." - Me neither. Post your code, otherwise it's very difficult to help.

Comment: Not sure how much is to much to post, but you can view the source here: http://www.crossroad-design.com/

Comment: I've taken out the CSS for text shadow on that page obviously because it wasn't working. But I'm a novice at this (I usually use WordPress, elgantthemes and so on) and so I'm thinking maybe I'm just putting the text shadow css code in the wrong place? I was putting it at the header area, where I have the table shadow stuff.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that header is the wrong place for it.
You should place it at your text divs. If you don't have a div for your text, create a class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "text-shadow" (ie. text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;)
Take a look at parameter definition [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp). 
Here is the code, you can also try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Salaros/EczY5/82/

```
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #000;
      background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAO0lEQVQYlWNgYGD4TyRGcIx1jeEYp0JkRTgUM8AF0RWhKUYVwMVmwGUtFutR3YjOJs8z6B7C4j7iFQIAm8p5b8pC31AAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
      ) repeat;
    }
    div#wrapper {
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      min-height: 100%;
      background-color: #000;
      box-shadow: 15px 0px 10px -5px #888, -15px 0px 10px -5px #888;
    }
    div#wrapper p {
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #FFF;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
    }
  </style>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <br />
      <p>Here you go!</p>
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357596/how-to-add-a-text-shadow-to-my-table-using-css">Go back to the question</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```